# Git Working Directory to Eclipse Workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I have been building my maven project(s) within my spring tool suite work space and have now decided that I need to get busy with some version control.

I have gone for GIT and have used the command line client to produce a local repository.

So, I have a local repo - which is ready to implements version control and a workspace with a load of files.

I am using the GIT plugin for Eclipse. See the image below.

[image]

How am I able to somehow synchronise my workspace with my git working directory so I can start to stage and commit indexes to Github?

Many thanks

//** EDIT **//

Okay - having found [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#respository) blog

I realized it is a simple project->team->share project option in the Eclipse Project Context Menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog post](http://programmingandelse.blogspot.com/2011/02/eclipse-egit-github-quick-guide-to.html) (from [Lucas Piva Rocha Corrêa](http://www.blogger.com/profile/16522642976242977785)) details the step you need to follow to share your local git project on GitHub;

- that includes the "Team Share" you found
- but it also mentions the ssh settings you need to get right in order to be able to push to an https GitHub address.

### Configuring Eclipse

> - Go to `Windows -> Preferences` and filter SSH. Select `SSH2` on the left tab (should be under General -> Network connections).
> - Check that `SSH2` home is set to `/home/<yourusername>/.ssh` and `id_rsa` is in Private Keys.
> - On `Key Management` tab, click on `Load Existing Key`... and select your `id_rsa` (private) key under `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. If your key has a non-empty passphrase, eclipse will not be able to load it, even if you provide the correct password.
> - Now, just save it in the same location you loaded it from, confirm empty passphrase, overwrite it, apply and click ok.

### Pushing your project to your github repo

> Final step is to push your project to your remote repository on github.
>
> - Finally, select the project you want to push to your created repository, right click it, go to `Team -> Share Project`... and select `git`.
> - Select your project, click on Create Repository and Finish. Now you should be able to commit and update changes to your local git repository.
> - To push it to your remote GitHub repo, right click your project, select `Team -> Remote -> Push`...
> - Fill the URI with your project SSH address, which is shown when you enter your repository page on GitHub.
> - Select `ssh protocol`, user is `git` and empty password.
> - Cross your fingers, hit next. If it doesn't work for some reason at this point, try restarting Eclipse (it worked for me after restart).
> - Select Source Ref and Destination Ref (basically the branch), click on Add Spec and Finish on the next screen.
> - Hopefully everything goes well.

Comment: On eclipse 4.2.2 and with eGit 2.2 on OSX, I followed this instruction of saving an id_rsa_eclipse without passphrase from eclipse. When I try to do a team synchronize on my repo, I got a popup asking me "Provide information for ssh://git@github.com:22, passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa_eclipse. The empty nor the original password are working. And it keep asking. Any idea ?